# Copy and change javascript function scope

Tags: javascript

Is there any way to copy a JavaScript function Scope to another function?

```
(function(v){
     var Ct=v.Ct=function(){
     }
     var a="asdf";

     Ct.prototype.fun=function(){
          console.log(a);    //prints 'asdf'
     }
})(window)

--------------------------------------------------
```

the above code cannot be changed:

how to rewrite Ct.prototype.fun to make it print 'asdfasdf'

the following example can not get "a"

```
Ct.prototype.fun=function(){
    console.log(a+a);   //It's not work
}

var o=new Ct();
o.fun();
```

Comment: Use `this` and then `apply()`, `call()`, `bind()` and any others I may be missing.  Bending explicit lexically scoped variables outside of that would be a recipe for pain if it is possible.

Comment: You don't have access to `a` from outside. Is `a` different for every instance? If so then use `this.a` inside the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

```
(function(v){
 var Ct=v.Ct=function(){
 };
 var a="asdf";

 Ct.prototype.fun=(function(){
    return function(){
      console.log(a+a);    //prints 'asdf' 
 }
 })(a);
})(window);
var o=new Ct();
o.fun();
```

Answer (score 0):

If there's a pre-existing variable or something similar that you want access to you could provide a getter within the initial closure and then access it through the context.

```
(function(v){
     var Ct=v.Ct=function(){
     }
     var a="asdf";

     Ct.prototype.fun=function(){
          console.log(a);    //prints 'asdf'
     }
     Ct.prototype.getA = function() {
        return a; 
     }
})(window)

Ct.prototype.fun=function(){
    console.log(this.getA()+this.getA());
}

var o=new Ct();
o.fun();
```

For anything more planned you'd be better off re-thinkng how you're using objects.

Comment: @user1965351 I don't understand your comment

Comment: sorry, clear up the question:
in fact, the following code cannot be changed:
(function(v){
     var Ct=v.Ct=function(){
     }
     var a="asdf";

     Ct.prototype.fun=function(){
          console.log(a);    //prints 'asdf'
     }
})(window)

Comment: If you can't change the code then there's no good way to do it.  An ugly hack for the above code would be to temporarily redefine the `console` variable with a `log` method that just collects the value for you.  You could then call the original function to retrieve the value.  The old function could be moved to an alias and replaced by a new function which does all this for you before finally performing the behavior you're after.

Comment: Thanks a lot.There is a "[[Scope]]" in the EMCAScript, a scope chain that defines the environment in which a Function object is executed. I wanna get the Scope of the original function, redefine a new function and reset the Scope.Such as Function.bind can change the [this] Variable. The question is only in my mind. Thranks for you answer.